# Google cloud Postgresql connection timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postgresql

I just created a postgreSQL instance on GCP, I have allowed public IP connections, and added both `0.0.0.0` and `0.0.0.0/32` to the IP allow lists, I don't require SSL connection and even added a new user, however I keep getting `timeout` errors and can't access my database

Comment: Run a connectivity test, check the output and validate the firewall rule and even if there ara firewall policies blocking the connectivity

Comment: Never allow public access directly to a database service.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, the IP allow list value needs to be `0.0.0.0/0`